# Download Manager is not showing file in Gallery after downloading from webview

Tags: java, android, url, webview, android-download-manager

I want to download image from my webview, a notification comes and it downloads the file but when i go to Gallery then the file is not there.What i'm doing wrong ... ??

```
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(geturl));
        request.setTitle("File Download");
        request.setDescription("File is being downloaded...");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(geturl, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(geturl));

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this,Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM,nameOfFile);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)getApplication().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
```

While geturl is the Override url by which i am taking the url of an image.

```
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //Get url for downloading
        geturl = url;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: what `it's not working` means? do you have any errors?

Comment: @Yazan I don't have any errors, even the notification comes and download the file but when i go to Gallery then the file is not there ...

Comment: this should be your title, instead of `not working`